# Are there any variables available inside the package.json environment?

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I would like to optionally install dependencies for my deployments based on environment configuration of my node servers, is this possible?

Something like :

```
dependencies : env.prod == true ? {} : {something : "1.1" }
```

Are there any variables available at this stage in the npm install stage?

Comment: That is not valid json syntax.

Comment: do you need more than development vs. production? if not, you can use `devDependencies` for the ones you don't want in production (other way wont work though- you can have dev only packages, not production only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many organizations run their own node repositories.  This has the advantage that your production won't fail to deploy because some third party repository went down.

If you can run your own node repository, why not run two (or more).  Then you can put mock packages in the "staging" repository and the real packages in the "production" repository.

It seems that this would achieve the effect you are trying for, but I fail to see the point.

Comment: the reason is that I have to deploy for windows servers and macOS servers for which I want to run different build processes,etc because of business reason,etc,etc. Thank you btw.

Comment: @MaG3Stican I always deploy to linux servers running on a VM.  Don't really understand why anyone would do differently.

Comment: @MaG3Stican It seems like they are separate projects and you should have separate package.json files